# iOS Build successed by Emulator, but failed by Remote Device

Tags: ios, cordova

I try to build iOS App from my Win10 in Parallels Desktop. Building Emulator is OK, but I want a .ipa file and try "Remote Device", and has following Error.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       Specified application doesn't exist or isn't a bundle directory : 'platforms/ios/build/device/io.cordova.myapp474c62.app'   HuaheWeb    C:\Projectes\HuaheWeb\HuaheWeb\MDAVSCLI 1
Error       Specified application doesn't exist or isn't a bundle directory : 'platforms/ios/build/device/io.cordova.myapp474c62.app'   HuaheWeb    C:\Projectes\HuaheWeb\HuaheWeb\MDAVSCLI 1
Error       Specified application doesn't exist or isn't a bundle directory : 'platforms/ios/build/device/io.cordova.myapp474c62.app'   HuaheWeb    C:\Projectes\HuaheWeb\HuaheWeb\MDAVSCLI 1
Error       Remote build error from the build server Build failed with error Command failed: /bin/sh -c xcrun -v -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication platforms/ios/build/device/io.cordova.myapp474c62.app -o /Users/mai/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/844/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/device/xxx.ipa HuaheWeb    C:\Projectes\HuaheWeb\HuaheWeb\MDAVSCLI 1
Error       Specified application doesn't exist or isn't a bundle directory : 'platforms/ios/build/device/io.cordova.myapp474c62.app'   HuaheWeb    C:\Projectes\HuaheWeb\HuaheWeb\MDAVSCLI 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when building a Cordova app for iOS using Visual Studio 2015 Update 1. In my case it was a problem with the Cordova CLI version - I used "5.4.0" which gave the same errors as you have.

Then I switched back to "5.3.3" (the default version of a new Cordova project in VS) and now it successfully builds the .ipa file.